# Getting the last match in a file using grep

Tags: unix, grep

What's the best way of getting only the final match of a regular expression in a file using grep?

Also, is it possible to begin grepping from the end of the file instead of the beginning and stop when it finds the first match?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You could try

```
grep pattern file | tail -1
```

or

```
tac file | grep pattern | head -1
```

or

```
tac file | grep -m1 pattern
```

Comment: `tac file | grep -m 1 pattern`

Comment: With the added constraint that I wanted to get the line number (`grep -n`) in the actual file, I think `tac` pretty much had to be avoided, unless I wanted to do some subtraction with `wc -l`. Otherwise `tac` with `grep -m1` makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I'd love to see a more performant version than this, since I am trying to search a 20GB file.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson 's answer is much better because `grep` will stop working after the first match. without `-m 1`, `grep` will first **find all matching patterns in the file**, then `head` will show only the first - much less efficient.
Dennis, please consider posting this in a separate answer!

Comment: To keep grep colors when piping, use `--color=always`. Tail works great when grepping multiple files (e.g. `grep pattern -r path`), but `tac` option is not recommended for multiple files (probably have high memory consumption).

Answer (score 2):

I am always using cat (but this makes it a little longer way): `cat file | grep pattern | tail -1`

I would blame my linux admin course teacher at college who love cats :))))

-- You don't have to cat a file first before grepping it. `grep pattern file | tail -1` and is more efficient, too.

Comment: This is just the first part of Cakemox's answer, except worse.

Comment: It works, but it does unnecessary steps. For light usage, this solution works fine, but it does not perform well. The reason is because you don't need to `cat` the file and pipe it to `grep`. You can have `grep` search the file directly via `grep pattern file` (and then use `tail` to return the last result), as in Cakemox's answer.

Answer (score 2):

For someone working with huge text files in Unix/Linux/Mac/Cygwin. If you use Windows checkt this out about Linux tools in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519738/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-linux-utilities-under-windows.

One can follow this workflow to have good performance:

1. compress with gzip
2. use zindex (on github:
       https://github.com/mattgodbolt/zindex) to index the file with
       appropriate key
3. query the indexed file with `zq` from the package.

Quote from its github readme:

**Creating an index**

> zindex needs to be told what part of each line constitutes the index.
>   This can be done by a regular expression, by field, or by piping each
>   line through an external program.
>
> By default zindex creates an index of file.gz.zindex when asked to
>   index file.gz.
>
> Example:
>
> create an index on lines matching a numeric regular
>   expression. The capture group indicates the part that's to be indexed,
>   and the options show each line has a unique, numeric index.
>
> ```
> $ zindex file.gz --regex 'id:([0-9]+)' --numeric --unique
> ```
>
> Example:
>   create an index on the second field of a CSV file:
>
> ```
> $ zindex file.gz --delimiter , --field 2
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> create an index on a
>   JSON field orderId.id in any of the items in the document root's
>   actions array (requires jq). The jq query creates an array of all the
>   orderId.ids, then joins them with a space to ensure each individual
>   line piped to jq creates a single line of output, with multiple
>   matches separated by spaces (which is the default separator).
>
> ```
> $ zindex file.gz --pipe "jq --raw-output --unbuffered '[.actions[].orderId.id] | join(\" \")'"
> ```

**Querying the index**

> The zq program is used to query an index. It's given the name of the
>   compressed file and a list of queries. For example:
>
> ```
> $ zq file.gz 1023 4443 554
> ```
>
> It's also possible to output by line
>   number, so to print lines 1 and 1000 from a file:
>
> ```
> $ zq file.gz --line 1 1000
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions only work for one single file, to print the last occurrence for **many files** (say with suffix `.txt`), use the following bash script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for fn in `ls *.txt`
do
    result=`grep 'pattern' $fn | tail -n 1`
echo $result
done
```

where `'pattern'` is what you would like to grep.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several files, use inline-for:

```
for a in *.txt; do grep "pattern" $a /dev/null | tail -n 1; done
```

The /dev/null provides a second file so grep will list the filename where the pattern is found.

Comment: It might be useful if `$a` variable is empty, but that is all.